# Django ordering by date_created with ManyToMany using Through

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Having trouble figuring out how to order by date created. I've looked at some similar problems on here and no fix. I need the dates to order by ascending so that the most recent object created is on the top of the list. I've tried different things even using JS to revert the list and still no luck.

I have:

```
class Info(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='cb_section')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='up_section')
    date_created = models.DateField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField('Date updated', auto_now=True)

    

class Section(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    section_infos = models.ManyToManyField(Info, through='SectionInfo')
    date_created = models.DateField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField('Date updated', auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_section_info(self):
        return self.section_infos.order_by('-date_created')




class SectionInfo(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey(Info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('info__date_created',)
```

and in my template I have

```
<div class="row">
    {% for object in object_list %}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h1><strong>{{ object.name }}</strong></h1>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <div class="row">       
                    {% for info in object.section_infos.all %}
                    
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li>{{ info.date_created }}</li> |
                        <li><a href="{% url 'manufacturing:section_info_detail' info.id %}">{{ info.detail }}</a></li>
                        <hr>
                    </ul>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

View for this is

```
# view list of all sections and section infos
def view_sections(request):
    object_list = Section.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')

    context = {
        'object_list':object_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'manufacturing/view_sections.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply `ordering=['-date_created']` in descending order in `Info` model which will fetch the latest date from `date_created` field.

models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='cb_section')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='up_section')
    date_created = models.DateField('Date created', auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField('Date updated', auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
         ordering=['-date_created']
```

And remove <s>`ordering = ('info__date_created',)`</s> from `SectionInfo` model.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75269979/10495300

I hope it will help you to Django ordering by date_created with ManyToMany using Through. In ManyToMany there is no created date store. So you need to use id. Id also like created date